# jquery.js Dynamic Code Evaluation: Code Injection on setTimeout() line

Tags: appsec, javascript, sql-injection, injection, jquery

I am working on fixing a potential security issue. I ran my HP fortify SCA and I got a critical priority report on my jquery.js file.

> Category : Dynamic Code Evaluation: Code Injection (3 Issues).

I looked at the source code and it turns out to be the line where the `setTimeout()` eval code sits.

```
if (s.async && s.timeout) {
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout( function() {
        jqXHR.abort("timeout");
    }, s.timeout );
}
```

with a try catch block preceding.

I did a couple of digging and they say do not mess with the third party source code, you may be tampering with other functionalities. I'm thinking just suppress and move on? I usually do not like to suppress critical.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code it is complaining about? I don't see any code evaluation going on there.

Comment: The jquery.js file interprets unvalidated user input as source code on that line.Interpreting user-controlled instructions at run-time can allow a malicious attacker executes his code.

Comment: Technically, it's defining an anonymous function, which, if performed carelessly, can allow for dynamic execution. I would suspect an overly conservative rule picking up on this - and I'd guess that HP have seen this before, given how prevalent jquery is.

Comment: *"The jquery.js file interprets unvalidated user input as source code on that line."* I can confirm this code is not doing that. That's also a very bold claim it is making, seeing as no user input is seen on these lines. Perhaps that just what it says every time it sees `setTimeout` (setTimeout could evaluate code, if passed a string)? If that's the case, this tool is garbage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's a false positive.**

Reporting false code injection vulnerabilities is a well-known problem with HP Fortify and [has confused developers before](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/code-injection-in-jquery-files). Fortify just does basic static analysis of the Javascript code and can't go arbitrarily deep to understand how it works. As @AlexanderOMara suggested, it just seems to discover the *potentially* dangerous `setTimeout()` function which can, as `setInterval()`, take a string argument that would be executed as code, just like `eval()` does. This the sort of vulnerability, the tool aims to discover:

```
setTimeout('alert(' + document.location.hash.split('#')[1] + ')', 0);
```

But in your case there is no user-supplied, unfiltered input to the `setTimeout()` function and it therefore looks safe. Leaving you with a great conclusion from the linked thread:

> My advice is to stop running HP fortify reports. 
>   Or pay the five thousand, or whatever  dollars to go to their classes so you could actually understand their malarkey.